# How to use flags to check if something from the collection matches the flag

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I'm trying to use flags to filter collection and retrive certain objects.

Perhaps the example will show the issue.

I defined a class and an enum.

```
    public class ExampleFlagsDto
{
    public int FlagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}


[Flags]
public enum FlagsTypes
{
    None = 0,
    Small = 1 << 0 ,
    Medium = 1 << 1 ,
    Normal = 1 << 2,
    Large = 1 << 3,
    LargeAndNormal = Normal | Large,
    All = Normal | Medium | Small | Large,

}
```

Then I constructed a list as an example and tried to retrive 2 objects from the list.

```
   var examples = new List<ExampleFlagsDto>()
        {
            new ExampleFlagsDto
            {
                FlagId  = (int)FlagsTypes.Normal,
                Name = "First"
            },
            new ExampleFlagsDto
            {
                FlagId  = (int)FlagsTypes.Medium,
                Name = "Second"
            },
            new ExampleFlagsDto
            {
                FlagId  = (int)FlagsTypes.Large,
                Name = "Third"
            },
            new ExampleFlagsDto
            {
                FlagId  = (int)FlagsTypes.Small,
                Name = "Forth"
            },
        };

        var selected = examples.Where(C => C.FlagId == (int)FlagsTypes.LargeAndNormal).ToList();


        foreach (var flag in selected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(flag.Name);
        }
```

Of course, it doesn't work. I know that when it comes to bits, (int)FlagTypes.LargeAndNormal would result in a sum of bits of Large and Normal. I have no idea how it has to look like bitwise, though.

I'm looking for a way to change the

```
  examples.Where(C => C.FlagId == (int)FlagsTypes.LargeAndNormal).ToList();
```

to a solution that would result in selected having 2 objects from examples.

Comment: `var selectedAll = examples.Where(C => C.FlagId != (int)FlagsTypes.None).ToList();`?

Comment: Don't really like the flag arithmetic but you could also write: `examples.Where(C => C.FlagId & [FlagType here]  != 0).ToList()` which would work for all flags except None

Comment: I've edited my post to simulate situation that interested me more. I think It changes the solution a little bit. Sorry for the first version being not well-thought

Comment: I am confused what you are really trying to ask/solve here. You have a flag `LargeAndNormal` that has the bits for both `Large` **and** `Normal` set, but then your examples list does not contain a single object that has both the `Large` **and** `Normal` flag set. Since there is no object there that has both `Large` **and** `Normal` flag set, no object would satisfy/match/correlate with the `LargeAndNormal` flag, thus the result is simply no object (empty list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this solution:

```
var selectedAll = examples.Where(C => (C.FlagId & (int)FlagsTypes.All) == (int)C.FlagId).ToList();
```